# Limit checked , checkbox in bootstrap dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, datatable

I have this code below to click a checkbox in my `DataTable` and get the `IDs` and store in an array. For Example I have a 2 seperate `DataTables` First is for President and second is for the Senators.

We know that we can only vote 1 in President and for Senators we can choose many.

My problem here is I can check how many checkboxes in the `DataTables`. How to limit the checked checkboxes?.

> Still learning in bootstrap here.

**JS Code**

```
var dataTablestest = $("#tbltest").DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    info: true,
    search: true,
    stateSave: true,
    order: [[1, "asc"], [2, "asc"]],
    lengthMenu: [[50, 100, 200, -1], [50, 100, 200, "All"]],
    ajax: { "url": "/Voting/LoadTableTest" },

    columns:
    [
         { data: "testID", title: "", visible: false, searchable: false },
        { data: "Fullname", title: "FullName", sClass: "alignRight" },
        { data: "Position", title: "Position", sClass: "alignRight" },
        { data: "party", title: "Party", sClass: "alignRight" },
        { data: "ActionMenu", title: "Click to vote", searchable: false, orderable: false, sClass: "alignCenter",
            "mRender": function (data) {
                return '<center><label><input class="checkId" type="checkbox" id="chkvote_' + data + '" value=""/></label></center>';
            }
        }
    ]
});
var arrayIds = [];
$('#tbltest tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".checkId")) {
        var Ids = dataTablestest.row(this).data().testID;
        arrayIds.push(Ids);
        return
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I found an answer but there is a problem with it. My counter keeps increment every time I check a checkbox from my dataTable.

```
 $('#tbltest tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".checkId")) {
        if ($(e.target).is(":checked") == true) {
            CheckCount = CheckCount + 1;
            var Ids = dataTablestest.row(this).data().testID;
            if (CheckCount > 1) {
                return false;
            }
            arrayIds.push(Ids);
            return
        }
        else {
            CheckCount = parseInt(CheckCount) - parseInt(1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code below.. Thanks to all who view my thread.

```
 var arrayIds = [];
$('#tbltest tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".checkId")) {
        var Ids = dataTablestest.row(this).data().testID;
        if ($(e.target).is(":checked") == true) {
            var lenArray = arrayIds.length;
            if (lenArray < 1) {
                arrayIds.push(Ids);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = arrayIds.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (arrayIds[i] === Ids) {
                    arrayIds.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
});
```